# Preventing overwriting of files when using save() or save.image()

Tags: r, file

I am trying to find a way to stop accidental overwriting of files when using the save() and save.image() function in R.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `file.exists()` to test if the file is there, and if it is, append a string to the name.

Edit:

Thanks Marek, I'll expand on your idea a bit... he could add this to deal with both `save()` and `save.image()`

```
SafeSave <- function( ..., file=stop("'file' must be specified"), overwrite=FALSE, save.fun=save) {
  if ( file.exists(file) & !overwrite ) stop("'file' already exists")
  save.fun(..., file=file)
}
```

I would not overwrite save... if `source()` was used in a REPL session, users may not be aware of the function overwrite.

Comment: Does anyone know how to create a dialog box to notify the user that the file to be written already exists? The user may just close the R session without knowing and nothing is saved.

Answer (score 5):

As Vince wrote you could use `file.exists()` to check existence.

I suggest to replace original `save` function:

```
save <- function( ..., file=stop("'file' must be specified"), overwrite=FALSE ) {
  if ( file.exists(file) & !overwrite ) stop("'file' already exists")
  base::save(..., file=file)
}
```

You could write similar to replace `save.image()`.