# R: Help writing a general function to prevent overwriting files when saving objects

Tags: r, function, save

I'm trying to gain some control over when graphic objects are being saved and stumbled across this related post from 8+ years ago: `https://stackoverflow.com/a/1541872/5322644`
I'd like to come up with a more general approach and below is my current attempt.  Of course, it doesn't work and so I'd appreciate some help on it.

```
 ## safely avoid overwriting files when saving objects using a user specified save.function 

safeSave <- function(save.function = save, ..., file=stop("'file' must be specified"), overwrite=FALSE ) {
  if ( file.exists(file) & !overwrite ) stop("'file' already exists")
  do.call(save.function, as.list( ..., file = file))
}
    
## Try using function.
## It appears to be trying to save the value of `tmp` rather than the variable `tmp`
tmp = 10
safeSave(save, tmp, file = "tmp.Rda") 
# Error in (function (..., list = character(), file = stop("'file' must be specified"),  : object ‘10’ not found
```

Comment: What's the advantage of using `do.call()` instead of just `save()` in this case?

Comment: save.function is a variable and the user (me) might want to use ggsave or similar. My understanding is that `save.function(..., file = file)` won't work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what I learned: when using `save()`, use the name of your object as a string. I also changed `as.list()` to `list()`, but I'm not sure why this made a difference.

Your function with slight modifications:

```
safeSave <- function(save.function = save, ..., file=stop("'file' must be specified"), overwrite=FALSE ) {
  if ( file.exists(file) & !overwrite ) stop("'file' already exists")
  do.call(save.function, list(..., file = file))
}
```

I had some issues getting `save()` to work, so I tried `saveRDS()`:

```
## Test with saveRDS()

tmp <- 10
file = "tmp.rds"
safeSave(saveRDS, tmp, file = file) 

# Check if file exists
file.exists(file)
#> [1] TRUE
# Correct contents
a <- readRDS(file)
a
#> [1] 10

# Attempt to overwrite
safeSave(save, "tmp", file = file)
#> Error in safeSave(save, "tmp", file = file): 'file' already exists
```

That worked fine.

Now `save()`. Note that I'm using `"tmp"` instead of `tmp`:

```
## Test with save()

file <- "tmp.rda"
tmp <- 10
safeSave(save, "tmp", file = file)

# Clean envir then load from file
rm(list=ls())
file <- "tmp.rda"
load(file)
tmp
#> [1] 10
```